# How to make SCIP use the LAPACK library?

Tags: lapack, scip

I have built a MINLP model in Pyomo in Linux system and I used SCIP to solve the model. Then I encountered the problem shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmnF7.png)

Then SCIP starts optimization and takes a large amount of time. I googled the problem and found that SCIP is only able to use LAPACK through Ipopt. Then I followed the instruction to run make IPOPT=true (I have installed IPOPT). However, build failed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXvAk.png)

Then I followed its suggestion to run make IPOPT=true READLINE=false ZLIB=false GMP=false and then new question appeared.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlgVi.png)

As for this question, I haven’t found any solution. When I run make GMP=true, it suggests me to use GMP=false, and when I run make GMP=false, it suggests me to use GMP=true.

So is there a way to make SCIP use the LAPACK library?

Answer (score 0):

For the GMP=false/true issue, I suspect that the problem is that SoPlex was built with GMP=true and SCIP needs GMP=true as well. So if you want to try to build SCIP with GMP=false then SoPlex should also be built with GMP=false.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really say from your pictures why linking against Ipopt failed. Check all error messages and whether the symbols that the compiler thinks are missing are actually available in the lib that is linked against.

Use VERBOSE=true to see the actual linker call and check whether it makes sense.

The hints about readline, gmp, or zlib are misleading. Don't deactivate these if you do not actually have problems linking against these libs.

If you want only Lapack but no Ipopt, then there has been a post about this a while ago: [lapack library for scip optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975673/lapack-library-for-scip-optimization)